# SwiftUI - Keyboard pushing my view including toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

So I have a view in NavigationStack with a custom toolbar. When keyboard pops up, all of my view pushing up including toolbar. I throw .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom) everywhere but no results. Also tried wrapping the view into a ScrollView, toolbar did not move but it's borderline became visible and I don't want that.

I need to achive this: Only the TextInput moves up when keyboard is visible.

I have been trying to achive this for 4 hours and this is crazy... What am I doing wrong?

```
ZStack{
    NavigationStack {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack{
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .frame(width: 370, height: 500)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 244 / 255, green: 246 / 255, blue: 251 / 255))
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()
                            .environmentObject(userViewModel)) {
                                ZStack{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: 300, height: 75)
                                    Text("bla bla bla")
                                        .lineLimit(2)
                                        .frame(width: 265, height: 75)
                                        .font(.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 15))
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                }
                                .padding(.top, 15)
                            }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 370, height: 500, alignment: .center)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    promtIsFocused = false
                }
            
            HStack {
                TextField("Type something", text: $text)
                    .font(.custom("Roboto-Regular", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .focused($promtIsFocused)
                NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()
                    .environmentObject(userViewModel)) {
                    Image("send")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                }
                .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    promtIsFocused = false
                    text = ""
                })
            }
            .padding(.all)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .stroke(Color(red: 229 / 255, green: 230 / 255, blue: 235 / 255), lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .background(Color(red: 244 / 255, green: 246 / 255, blue: 251 / 255)
                .cornerRadius(30))
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .padding(.vertical, 15)
            .padding(.top, geometry.size.height * 0.9)
        }
        .background(.white)
        .onTapGesture {
            promtIsFocused = false
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 30)
                .padding(.leading, 7)
        }
        
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 229 / 255, green: 230 / 255, blue: 235 / 255))
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                    HStack{
                        Image("stars")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 40)
                    }
                }
            }

            Button(action:{
                isSideMenuOpened.toggle()
            }) {
                Image("menu")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 22)
                    .padding(.leading, 7)
            }
        }
    }
}
SideMenu(isShowing: $isSideMenuOpened, showingPaywall: $showingPaywall, attemts: $attempts)
    .environmentObject(userViewModel)
}
```

Comment: Have you figured this out?